# Outlook WEB Add-in execution of getAccessToken returns status code 302

Tags: javascript, azure, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I strictly follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#configure-the-add-in) to build an Outlook WEB Add-in, but when I execute [getAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#add-client-side-code) I receive 302:

> Missing grant for this add-in.

with name:

> Preauthorization missing

Why is that? My Add-in is well registered in the [portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). Do I need to do anything else? What is the grant type for this request and where should I put it in?

```
$("#getAccessTokenBtn").click(function () {
        Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {
            if ("succeeded" === result.status) {
                // Use this token to call Web API
                var ssoToken = result.value; 
            } else {
                if (13003 === result.error.code) {
                    // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
                    // work or school (Office 365) or Microsoft Account IDs.
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my manifest:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
  <Requirements>
    <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
      <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </bt:Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        ...
    </Host>
  </Hosts>

  <Resources>
    ...
  </Resources>

  <WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>94x668mb-461c-4r4e-851n-fb9721222e31</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:44374/94x668mb-461c-4r4e-851n-fb9721222e31</Resource>
    <Scopes>
      <Scope>profile</Scope>
      <Scope>user.read</Scope>
    </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
</VersionOverrides>
```

I found the [troubleshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#13005) that suggests for error 13005 the following:

> **13005** 
>   Invalid Grant. This usually means that Office has not been pre-authorized to the add-in's web service. For more information, see [Create the service application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#create-the-service-application) and [Register the add-in with Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet#register-the-add-in-with-azure-ad-v20-endpoint) (ASP.NET) or [Register the add-in with Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs#register-the-add-in-with-azure-ad-v20-endpoint) (Node JS). This also may happen if the user has not granted your service application permissions to their *profile*.

What does that even mean?

Before I ask for Access Token, should I consent following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/grant-admin-consent-to-an-add-in), by just navigating to the the URL below?

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=94x668mb-461c-4r4e-851n-fb9721222e31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When developing, you have to grant admin consent as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/grant-admin-consent-to-an-add-in).

Another possibility for why you are getting that error is that you haven't preauthorized Outlook to the addin. When you register the add-in with AAD 2.0, be sure that you've done step 10 of this article: [Register SSO add-in with AAD 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2). Finally, if you haven't already, check out this article for any special factors that apply to Outlook addins: [Authenticate (Outlook) user with an SSO token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token)

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be the solution. I actually just found it prior to your answer but thanks!