# 'Preauthorization missing.' error when trying to get Access Token from Outlook AddIn

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, office-addins, azure-ad-graph-api

I am making an Outlook add-in in React and when trying to get the access token from OfficeRuntime, I get the following error:

This is the method I am trying to run:

```
    var bootToken = OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
      allowSignInPrompt: true
    });
```

This is the error in the browser console:
`OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'Preauthorization missing.', message: 'Missing grant for this add-in.', code: 13005} code: 13005 message: "Missing grant for this add-in." name: "Preauthorization missing."`

This is my manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>{AppId}</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Signator</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Signator Demo"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Signator demo"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Signator Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Signator Add-in"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
      <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>{AppId}</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/{AppId}</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
          <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
          <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
          <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
          <Scope>email</Scope>
          <Scope>access_as_user</Scope>
        </Scopes>
      </WebApplicationInfo>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

This is my .env file:

```
CLIENT_ID=6fd14366-13ed-4a8d-8563-0f89e8428f43
GRAPH_URL_SEGMENT_=/me
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3000
QUERY_PARAM_SEGMENT=
SCOPE=access_as_user
```

These are my API permissions:
[image: api permissions]

I also have declared a scope 'access_as_user' and generated a client secret, added all possible client apps, enabled authorization and sso and set the app to be multi tenant.

What could be the problem why do I get the error that **'Preauthorization is missing' (code 13005)**?

Comment: Have you tried using the `office-addin-sso` package for registering the web add-in in Azure? Do you get the same resutls?

Answer (score 0):

Under Manage, select API permissions, and select Add a permission. On    the panel that opens, choose Microsoft Graph, and then choose    **Delegated permissions**. Please check your permissions and see if  Files.Read.All is selected for appliation type permission and if    needs to be changed to delegated.

```
Files.Read.All
offline_access
openid
profile
```

- Please make sure to grant admin consent as an administrator.So please
  test tenants where you have **admin role** and from that you can
  provide all the consents. When developing, you have to grant admin
  consent as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/grant-admin-consent-to-an-add-in).
- Also try use this url and check to grant permissions for your  app:
  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`

  > see [Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent).
- Please refer [Outlook-Add-in-SSO /Office-Add-in-samples · GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth/Outlook-Add-in-SSO)
  which implements an outlook-add-in-sso-aspnet that uses Office's SSO
  feature to give the add-in access to Microsoft Graph data.
- And check in the ***Authorized client applications*** section,
  identify the applications that you want to authorize to your add-in's
  web application. **Each of the following IDs needs to be
  pre-authorized:**

for example In the Authorized client applications section, enter the following ID to pre-authorize all Microsoft Office application endpoints.
`ea5a67f6-b6f3-4338-b240-c655ddc3cc8e` (*All Microsoft Office application endpoints*)

***The ID, ea5a67f6-b6f3-4338-b240-c655ddc3cc8e  pre-authorizes Office on all the following platforms***.

> Note :Alternatively, you can enter a proper subset of the following
> IDs if for any reason you want to deny authorization to Office on some
> platforms. Just leave out the IDs of the platforms from which you want
> to withhold authorization.

```
d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c (Microsoft Office)
ea5a67f6-b6f3-4338-b240-c655ddc3cc8e (Microsoft Office)
57fb890c-0dab-4253-a5e0-7188c88b2bb4 (Office on the web)
08e18876-6177-487e-b8b5-cf950c1e598c (Office on the web)
bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3 (Outlook on the web)

For each ID, take these steps:
```

> a. Select Add a client application button, and in the panel that
> opens, set the Client ID to the respective GUID and check the box for
> api://localhost:44355/$App ID GUID$/access_as_user.
>
> b. Select Add application.

Please check these References:

1. [Register an Office Add-in that uses SSO with the Microsoft identity platform - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2#add-a-scope)  &    c[reate-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Authorized,GUID%24/access_as_user).
2. [oauth 2.0 - Error getting SSO in Outlook 365 web addin 13005. Preauthorization missing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095595/error-getting-sso-in-outlook-365-web-addin-13005-preauthorization-missing?noredirect=1#comment118604689_67095595).

Another possible cause, during development, is that your add-in using Internet Explorer, and you are using a self-signed certificate. (To determine which browser is being used by the add-in, see [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) ).

See [Troubleshoot error messages for single sign-on (SSO) - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#13005)

**References:**

1. [javascript - Outlook WEB Add-in execution of getAccessToken returns status code 302 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676796/outlook-web-add-in-execution-of-getaccesstoken-returns-status-code-302?msclkid=b06337a7d01e11ec964d42d09d0d73c3)
2. [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins?msclkid=7663db1ad01e11ecb35dad995acd78d9)